# Alex requies the result token type to be some function that takes a AlexPosn

Tags: haskell, typeerror, lexer, alex

I'm trying to write a lexer that lexes c-style comments and nothing else(for now).

```
{
module Lexer where

import Prelude hiding (head, take, tail)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy
}

%wrapper "monad-bytestring"

@not_bc_end = ~\* | \* ~\/


tl :-
  <0>   $white+             ;
  <0>   "/*"                { tok (\p s -> BCBegin p) `andBegin` bc }
  <bc>  .+ / not_bc_end     { tok (\p s -> BCContent p s) }
  <bc>  "*/"                { tok (\p s -> BCEnd p) `andBegin` 0 }
  <0>   "//"                { tok (\p s -> LCBegin p) `andBegin` lc }
  <lc>  .*$                 { tok (\p s -> LCContent p s) }

{
tok :: (AlexPosn -> ByteString -> Token) -> AlexInput -> Int64 -> Alex Token
tok f (p, _, bs, _) len = pure $ f p (take len bs)

data Token
  = LCBegin AlexPosn
  | LCContent AlexPosn ByteString
  | BCBegin AlexPosn
  | BCEnd AlexPosn
  | BCContent AlexPosn ByteString
  | End AlexPosn

alexEOF = pure End
}
```

The codegen succeeded but the compilation failed with the following error:

```
templates/wrappers.hs:288:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Token’ with ‘AlexPosn -> Token’
      Expected type: Alex (AlexPosn -> Token)
        Actual type: Alex Token
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: action (ignorePendingBytes inp__) len
      In the expression:
        do alexSetInput inp__'
           action (ignorePendingBytes inp__) len
      In the expression:
        let len = n' - n
        in
          do alexSetInput inp__'
             action (ignorePendingBytes inp__) len
```

The compiler complains that the token type (wrapped in `Alex`) have to take an argument of the type `AlexPosn`. I got confused because there's already an `AlexPosn` in the `AlexInput` and the user guide explicitly stated that the token type can bu anything as long as they are kept the same across all the tokens.

Changing the definition of `tok` to the following solved the problem:

```
tok :: (AlexPosn -> ByteString -> Token) -> AlexInput -> Int64 -> Alex (AlexPron -> Token)
tok f (_, _, bs, _) len = pure $ \p -> f p (take len bs)
```

But I have no idea why is Alex focing the token to take an `AlexPosn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I accidentally added a field of type `AlexPosn` to the constructor `End`